# How to dynamically load a html section inside a SPA shell in a PWA app

Tags: reactjs, progressive-web-apps

Our PWA app consists of a shell which is loaded once and use typical SPA techniques to load any new data from the back end. This shell behaves very much like a typical SPA.
Inside this shell is an area that shows only html. This html has to be loaded dynamically. Also, any back-end request that originate from this html has to be intercepted by the static part. For example, when user click on 'next' button which is inside the html, a new html has to be loaded.
Is this possible in a PWA and if so what techniques can be used?

Answer (score 1):

Should something like this work? You can parse HTML into elements tree while transforming link nodes, injecting your own onclick handler:

https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-html-parser